# how to read values from templatecache?

Tags: angularjs, angular-templatecache

I have generated a minified angular app with grunt. In the site I get an error:

```
Cannot GET /views/tabs.html
```

However when I look in the minified script.js I can see:

```
angular.module("app").run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
    "use strict";
 $templateCache.put("views/tabs.html", '<div>hello</div>'}
]);
```

How can I resolve this error? Why is it not visible to the application?

Comment: It's fetching `/views/tabs.html` but templateCache has `views/tabs.html` without the leading slash.

Comment: got it working now just needed to refresh